# Android mobile number verification

Tags: android

Hi guys I need help from you all in Android mobile number verification process. I have a android phone I just need to verify the otp but in this case they using the auto verification method is it possible to verify my otp through fwd the msg or by using prank message app Pls anyone help me to solve my problem and thx in advance...

Comment: Thank u sir fr ur valuable reply but It is possible sir I want to verify my mobile number on the app but the app only accepts the otp from particular number(e.g. Tx-RDSA) so with the help of prank message I can compose any msg with any number but the app doesn't accept the otp in normal way it only accept through the broadcast plz help me & thx in adv....

Comment: Ok, so you want to send a OTP to an app using the prank message app with the number the app accepts?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are asking for "how to implement OTP verification". There are number of ways to tackle this. Please look at the below link for two ways of achieving this using Google authenticator or using a SMS gateway.

[Android one time password (OTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400278/android-one-time-password-otp)

here is the tutorial to read the incoming messages using Broadcast receiver if you are going to use the second method.

["Reading incoming messages using broadcast receiver."](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to implement a way you can implement your own TTS (Text-To-Speech) Verification system that prompts the user to enter in the code.

If so, you can use Nexmo's Text To Speech Prompt.

All you have to do is make an HTTP call (For example: https://api.nexmo.com/tts-prompt/json)

From here you can use the parameters you want such as,

- text - Body of the text message to be read to the end user
- machine_detection - How to react when an answering machine is detected
- lg - To determine what language the text is read in
- bye_text - Body of the text message played after digits are entered successfully
- failed_text - Body of the text message played after 3 failed attempts

There are many other parameters you can work with and customize your TTS prompt to capture/confirm data.

*Full disclosure, I work at Nexmo*

You can see more information how to implement this [here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/text-to-speech-prompt)