# How to Validate One Time Password (OTP) for certain time period?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing a android app In which user need to verify mobile number through OTP. I'm successfully getting SMS on mobile number. I want to keep OTP valid only for 3-5 minutes.This is how i'm generating OTP for reference you can check this [Android one time password (OTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400278/android-one-time-password-otp]).

Comment: Where is the OTP generated (server or device) and where is it checked?

Comment: OTP is generating in device and saved using Shared Preferences. Verifying  received OTP from saved OTP.

Comment: Then simply delete it after 5 minutes. But in general, doing security on the device is often not a good idea. You don't have full control over the software that runs on the device.

Comment: Thanks @Henry for your valuable suggestion. So I should generate OTP from server side. Can you please tell me how validate on that scenario.

Comment: @Killing Klang Can you answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980037/how-to-achieve-zigzag-view-in-middle-of-cardview)